# Getting pitch, yaw and roll from Rotation Matrix in DH Parameter

Tags: kinematics, forward-kinematics, dh-parameters

I've calculated a DH Parameter matrix, and I know the top 3x3 matrix is the Rotation matrix. The DH Parameter matrix I'm using is as below, from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denavit%E2%80[image]

Above is what I'm using. From what I understand I'm just rotating around the Z-axis and then the X-axis, but most explanations from extracting Euler angles from Rotation matrixes only deal with all 3 rotations. Does anyone know the equations? I'd be very thankful for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, Euler angles (or specifically roll-pitch-yaw angles) can be extracted from *any* rotation matrix, regardless of how many rotations were used to generate it. For a typical x-y-z rotation sequence, you end up with this rotation matrix where **$\phi$ is roll, $\theta$ is pitch, and $\psi$ is yaw**:

$R = \begin{bmatrix} c_\psi c_\theta & c_\psi s_\theta s_\phi - s_\psi c_\phi & c_\psi s_\theta c_\phi + s_\psi s_\phi \\ s_\psi c_\theta & s_\psi s_\theta s_\phi + c_\psi c_\phi & s_\psi s_\theta c_\phi - c_\psi s_\phi \\ -s_\theta & c_\theta s_\phi & c_\theta c_\phi \end{bmatrix}$

Note that $c_x = \cos x$ and $s_x = \sin x$.

To get roll-pitch-yaw angles out of any given numeric rotation matrix, you simply need to relate the matrix elements to extract the angles based on trigonometry. So re-writing the rotation matrix as:

$R = \begin{bmatrix} R_{11} & R_{12} & R_{13} \\ R_{21} & R_{22} & R_{23} \\ R_{31} & R_{32} & R_{33} \end{bmatrix}$

And then comparing this to the above definition, we can come up with these expressions to extract the angles:

$\tan \phi = \frac{R_{32}}{R_{33}}$

$\tan \theta = \frac{-R_{31}}{\sqrt{R_{32}^2 + R_{33}^2}}$

$\tan \psi = \frac{R_{21}}{R_{11}}$

When you actually solve for these angles you'll want to **use an `atan2(y,x)` type of function so that quadrants are appropriately handled** (also keeping the signs of the numerators and denominators as shown above).

Note that this analysis **breaks down when $\cos \theta = 0$**, where there exists a singularity in the rotation -- there will be multiple solutions.

Also note that your question is referring to the rotation transformation *between* two joints ($^{n-1}R_n$), which is indeed composed of an x-axis and z-axis rotation, but the actual rotation of that joint with respect to the base will be different ($^0R_n$) and composed of all the rotations for joints 1 to $n$. I point this out because $^{n-1}R_n$ *can* be decomposed back into the relevant x-axis ($\alpha$) rotation and z-axis ($\theta$) rotation, whereas $^0R_n$ is better suited to roll-pitch-yaw -- especially for the end-effector.

Comment: I see! I've already finished calculating the overall transformation matrix ^0T_n, so I assume I just take the upper 3x3 matrix and use that as my ^0R_n so I can arrive at roll-pitch-yaw angles relative to the base using the equations you provided. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, you got it!

Comment: @Brian Lynch how the extraction will change If I need yaw pitch roll convention ?